# acces each class element by .blur jquery and send it to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a pricework class td formed in foreach

```
 foreach ()
   {
            <td>
            <input id="@item.ID" type="text" class="PriceWork form-control" value="@item.Price" style="width: 75px;">
            </td>
    }
     $('.PriceWork').blur(function () {


                 //var $this = $(this);
                var ValuePrice = this.value;
                var journalID = this.attributes.id;
                console.log(journalID);
                console.log(ValuePrice);

                var Data = {
                    id: $("#idText").val(),
                    journalID: journalID,
                    ValuePrice: ValuePrice
                };
                $.getJSON("/Acts/SetWorkPriceJSON", Data, setBookDisplay);

            });
```

I easily can output *ID* and Price but I can not send it to `SetWorkPriceJSON`. This is `null` or `$.getJSON` simply does not run controller. both variants are bad
What can I do?
Yesterday I found a solution for map with help. But I do not need map or arrays. Just one pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use jquery post call while sending an object, and always stringfy post data

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Acts/SetWorkPriceJSON"
        , type: 'POST'
        , contentType: 'application/json'
        , data: JSON.stringify(Data)
        , success: function () {
            // your succuss code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: OK. It helps me. it was earlier with .ajax. I can get value now but can not get send Id to controller.

Comment: ok. i use this.id for id. But why this.attributes.id not work?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to call SetWorkPriceJSON with "$.ajax" like the below way:

```
 $('.PriceWork').blur(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Acts/SetWorkPriceJSON",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id:$("#idText").val(),journalID:journalID,ValuePrice:ValuePrice},
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {                       

        },
        error: function (response) {

        }
    });
});
```

Cordially